# it is showing that 'gcc not found' on vs code even though mingwx64 is installed and is in system path variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc

i have mingwx64 installed on my device and is in the path variables as well
i can run it in terminal and powershell and pretty much everywhere but still in vs code it is showing my an error like this.[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44gnu.png)

also the c_cpp_properties.json file [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMGPO.png)

{

"configurations": [

```
{

  "name": "windows-gcc-x64",

  "includePath": [

    "${workspaceFolder}/**"

  ],

  "compilerPath": "gcc",

  "cStandard": "${default}",

  "cppStandard": "${default}",

  "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",

  "compilerArgs": []

}
```

],

"version": 4

}

please help...

Comment: You didn't set a **path** in `compilerPath`.

Comment: i have... it works in cmd, powershell, etc, everywhere

Comment: That's a different thing, so you'll have to specify the full path in `compilerPath`.